# Facebook graph extremely slow in PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

Whether using the Facebook PHP SDK, or just loading data using curl with `$contents = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$id?access_token=$accessToken")`, it takes around a whole second for the response to come.

That counts as very slow when I need to check the data for a bunch of ids.

When in a browser, if I type in a facebook graph url, I get the results almost instantly, under a tenth of the time it takes in PHP.

What is causing this problem, and how can I make it as fast as it would be in any browser? I know the browser can do it. There has to be a way to make it fast in PHP too.

IDEA: perhaps I need to configure something in cURL?

What I have tried:

- Using the PHP SDK. It's as slow. The reason I tried using `file_get_contents()` in the first place was because I was hoping the PHP SDK wasn't configured properly.
- Using `setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`. It didn't make a difference. AFTER ANSWER ACCEPT EDIT: actually, this together with reusing the curl handle made the subsequent requests really fast.

EDIT: here is a pastebin of the code I used to measure the time it takes to do the requests: http://pastebin.com/bEbuqq5g.
I corrected the text that used to say microseconds, to seconds. this is what produces results similar to the one I wrote in my comment in this question: [Facebook graph extremely slow in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412406/facebook-graph-extremely-slow-in-php#comment16127892_12073498). Note also that they take similarly slow times even if the access token is expired, like in my pastebin example.

EDIT 2: there should be partly a problem with ssl. I tried benchmarking http://graph.facebook.com/4 (no httpS), and it resulted in 1.2 seconds for three requests, whereas the same, but with https took 2.2 seconds. This is in no way a solution though, because for any request that needs an access token, I must use https.

Comment: PHP needs to fetch and process. But when you are using the Browser request directly goes to facebook server which makes it much more faster :-).

Comment: WHat do you mean? Doesn't file_get_contents() with a facebook url go to facebook directly? And if not, how _do_ I make it go to facebook directly?

Comment: I was telling about the difference you were comparing with `file_get_contents` and your browser. For the php script it first needs to parse that stuffs and get the content and give back to you. On the other hand it just send it on a fly.

Comment: I still do not understand. What does PHP parse that the browser doesn't?

Comment: try a javascript call instead of php , hopefully it performs better also be aware you can get all the ids in a single call , see facebook batch request

Comment: He means that in the browse request goes like A -> B -> A, where A is the browser, and with your php script it is A -> B -> C -> B -> A

Comment: have you tried requesting the graph on the same server your php is running on directly with curl or wget? how fast is it there?
problem with your browsers speed are http keep-alive and dns caching issues others have mentioned here already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wondered what would happen if I did two subsequent `curl_exec()` calls without doing a `curl_close()`, enabling the use of HTTP Keep-Alive.

The test code:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/xxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// FIRST REQUEST
curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));

// SECOND REQUEST
curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));

curl_close($ch);
```

Below are the results, showing parts of the output from [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php):

```
// FIRST REQUEST
[total_time] => 0.976259
[namelookup_time] => 0.008271
[connect_time] => 0.208543
[pretransfer_time] => 0.715296

// SECOND REQUEST
[total_time] => 0.253083
[namelookup_time] => 3.7E-5
[connect_time] => 3.7E-5
[pretransfer_time] => 3.9E-5
```

The first request is pretty slow, almost one whole second, similar to your experience. But from the time of the second request (only 0.25s) you can see how much difference the keep-alive made.

Your browser uses this technique as well of course, loading the page in a fresh instance of your browser would take considerably longer.

Comment: Okay, here is a pastebin of me running `curl_getinfo($ch)`:
http://pastebin.com/TG48UdRE
(one of the requests for the first curl example is the first print_r, and one of AndrewF's curl requests is the second)

Comment: @SzerémiAttila thanks, updated my answer; btw, you shouldn't leak your own access token in the paste ;p

Comment: Yea, yea, whatever, it'll run out anyway.
But anyway, the amending of your answer still doesn't help, because like I mentioned before, by typing https://graph.facebook.com/... into the browser directly, that should also be the same low priority, because it's all coming from my ip address and everything, but still it is much faster in the browser.
I would like to know why and what I can do to make curl be as fast as if I'd write the graph url into the browser.

Comment: @SzerémiAttila right you are, I wasn't thinking ... but I'm happy to report that I found out the difference :) updated answer.

Comment: So what this means is I could rewrite the Facebook PHP SDK so that it should try to reuse a single curl resource when querying data, instead of connecting and closing per request, and then the requests should be faster?

Comment: @SzerémiAttila right, that would be exactly my recommendation :) doesn't the sdk already do this if curl is available?

Comment: The facebook SDK seems to have that feature halfway implemented, because the `makeRequest()` method does accept a curl handle optionally for reuse, but the only method that calls this protected method is `_oauthRequest()`, and that never passes a curl handle.
This handle reuse way will work if even if I request different paths on https://graph.facebook.com/, won't it?

Comment: @SzerémiAttila yeah, it should. it will only disconnect when you're changing hosts :)

Answer (score 8):

`file_get_contents` can be very slow in PHP because it doesn't send/process headers properly, leading to the HTTP connection not getting closed properly when the file transfer is complete. I have also read about DNS issues, though I don't have any information about that.

The solution that I highly recommend is to either use the PHP SDK, which is designed for making API calls to Facebook, or make use of [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) (which the SDK uses). With cURL you can really configure a lot of aspects of the request, since it's basically designed for making API calls like this.

PHP SDK information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

PHP SDK source: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

If you choose to do it without the SDK, you could look at how they make use of cURL in [base_facebook.php](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php). here is some sample code you could use to fetch using cURL:

```
function get_url($url)
{
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);  // Return contents only
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  // return results instead of outputting
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10) // Give up after connecting for 10 seconds 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);  // Only execute 60s at most
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);  // Don't verify SSL cert
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   return $response;
}

$contents = get_url("https://graph.facebook.com/$id?access_token=$accessToken");
```

The function will return FALSE on failure.

I see that you said you've used the PHP SDK, but maybe you didn't have cURL set up. Try [installing or updating](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php) it, and if it still seems to be slow, you should use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
```

and check out the output.

Comment: Unfortunately the Facebook SDK was the first thing I used.
I purposely posted my problem in the format of `file_get_contents()` to show that even without the overhead of the Facebook SDK, the requests always take an abnormally long time.
`file_get_contents()` is neither faster nor slower than using the PHP SDK.

Comment: I also tested your code and it wasn't faster enough.

    Verbose time (some curl code I found somewhere): 2.5703480243683 microseconds.
    File get contents time:3.0643820762634 microseconds.
    AndrewF time: 2.3033740520477 microseconds.

Comment: @SzerémiAttila how are you testing these times?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry, so I couldn't verify what I wrote.
The times I posted are in seconds, not microseconds, like I wrote, which is my mistake. I also didn't write that these times are for loops of 3 of the same request per type of connection, so you'd divide these by 3 to get a more realistic insight of the speed, so they take about 0.7-1 second each.

And here is a pastebin of AndrewF's curl request's result: http://pastebin.com/Nh9yy73T

Comment: @SzerémiAttila ok, what *command* are you using to test these times. If you are calling it three times then how are you putting a benchmark next to the browser request

Comment: Oh I'm sorry... `$start = microtime(true); <facebook requests here...> echo microtime(true) - $start;`;
I set the start time for each one properly before their test, before the loop.

Comment: Are you only making this query with the same used every time? Try another user, like 4. Also, what happens when you try a non-secure API call with public access like http://graph.facebook.com/4 ?

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed this comment of yours yesterday.

I amended my post, including your experiment.

Comment: Ah I didn't see how you were mentioning benchmarking the browser. It seems the evidence is against me, because the javascript benchmark shows that the times are about the same (also, three requests): 
2.940999984741211 
So that clears javascript... but when I type in a browser window, it still seems so fast... try it and see what I mean. I feel like I can spam it easily. Is it just an illusion?

Answer (score 2):

Just two thoughts:

1. Have you verified that the browser doesn't have a presistent connection to facebook? That the browser hasn't cached the DNS lookup (you could try adding graph.facebook.net to your hosts-file to rule in/out DNS)
2. You are of course running the php code from the same system/environment as your browser (not from a vm, not from another host? Also that php is running with the same scheduling priorties as your browser? (same nice level etc))

Comment: One possible next step would be to do a packet capture, and look at the flow there -- to get a better idea of the timing (browser vs php).

Answer (score 1):

The overall biggest factor in making Graph API calls “slow” is – the HTTP connection.

Maybe there’s a *little* improvement in there by tweaking some parameters or getting a server with a better connection.

But this will most likely make no *big* difference, as HTTP is generally to be considered “slow”, and there’s little that can be done about this.

> That counts as very slow when I need to check the data for a bunch of ids.

The best thing you can do to speed things up is, of course – **minimize the number of HTTP requests.**

If you have to do several Graph API calls in a row, try doing them as a [Batch Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) instead. That allows you to query several portions of data, while at the same time making only *one* HTTP request.

Comment: But like I said, when doing it in the browser, it is much faster, and that uses http too. I would like to reach the speed at least as fast as the browser.

There may be something with the overhead of the ssl part. I'll amend my first post.

Answer (score 0):

This is purly a speculation, however the cause might be that Facebook uses the SPDY protocol (not sure wheter that's true for the API). PHP is not able to load the page using the SPDY protocol.